# Firebase Database User Authentication: Create User Email and Password with UID from Phone Provider

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

All my existing users have been authenticated using Phone Authentication method. But now we want to implement the Email and Password authentication method. For the present users, is it possible to link their accounts to the email and password authentication method using UID from the Phone method?

I am looking at the below:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password).push(UID).
```

Again the UID is retrieved from the Phone Provider Method. With this, we expect that Firebase will create the user with the same UID as that of the Phone Provider not a new UID. Is this possible?

I am implementing this using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is known as [account linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) in Firebase Authentication. The flow is:

1. The user signs in (in your case with phone auth).
2. You create credentials for an additional provider ([email+password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-email-address-and-password-credentials-to-a-user-account) in your case).
3. You then link the new credentials to the existing account.

After this, the user will retain their UID from phone auth, but they can now sign in with both providers. You can repeat the process for other providers too if you want.

Comment: Yes I know it is account linking but looking for a command that will allow me to create the user (email+password) using the UID of the user from Phone Provider.

Comment: That's not how it works. You create `EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password)` for the user, and then link them by calling `linkWithCredential`. I recommend trying it, and posting back with a code snippet if you're having a hard time making it work.